# Find the expected value of $Y$. Compute $E(|X-Y|)$

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X$ be a random variable distributed uniformly $E(|X-Y|)$ over $[0, 20]$. Define a new
random variable $Y$ by $Y = [X]$ (the greatest integer in $X$). Find the expected
value of $Y$.  Compute $E(|X-Y|)$.

**Attempt:**

I attempted to set up the integral $$\int_{0}^{1}\frac 1 {20}\,dx,$$ since I found out that it was uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$. Also, I thought the distribution fuction woud be $\dfrac 1 {20}$. Then, I used the formula $E(|X-Y|)=[E(X|X \ge Y)-Y]×P(X\ge Y)+[Y-E(X|X<Y)]×P(X<Y)$.

In the end, I ended up getting $\dfrac{Y^2}{20}-\dfrac Y {20}+\dfrac 1 {40}$.

How would u solve this?

Answer (score 1):

$$\forall X \geq 0, X-[X] \geq 0 \implies \forall X \geq 0, |X-[X]| = X-[X]$$

$$E(|X-[X]|) = E(X-[X]) = E(X)-E([X])$$

$$E(X) = 10$$

$$E([X]) = \int_{0}^{20}[x]\frac{1}{20}dx = \frac{1}{20}\left(\sum_{i=0}^{19}i\right) = \frac{19}{2}$$